# JavaFX App looks different in built jar than when running it inside intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

I'm facing this weird issue, where the gui app I'm developing looks **scaled down** when run **inside intellij** than it does when run **outside**. Here's a demo image:

[image: The window on the right is ran inside intellij]

Weird thing is, I like how it is scaled down. Why does this happen, and is it possible to **reproduce** it outside of Intellij A?

Comment: are you running the same java ? afterall, you probably check your setting(s) in IntelliJ to see how (which command and arguments) exactly your app was run in there. This will enable you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Display with high DPI ? If so, the problem could be, that Java tells windows that it will handle the resizing itself. Its called DPI-Aware. You could disable this, than it will look the same as in your IDE.